# Как реализовать массив и вызов значений из него

Tags: массивы, php

В РНР я вобще слаб, но вот что хочу сделать: значения массива хранятся в текстовом файле(пусть это будут строчки из какой-нибудь песни), а на сайте есть кнопка, нажимая на которую пользователь каждый раз видит новую строчку из песни (но не по порядку, а выбранную произвольно). При нажатии кнопки не должна открываться новая страница, все должно происходить на одной. Как это все реализовать? Как правильно сделать такой массив, и какой код должен быть на сайте?

Comment: а в чем Вы не слабы? AJAX Вам в помощь

Comment: @eicto на вас нет! Он бы давно уже закрыл вопрос с комментарием "на биржу фрилансеров"! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Создаете файл с цитатами (скажем так: каждая цитата -> новая строка)

  PHP

- Открываете файл
- Находите кол-во строк
- Генерируете число от 0 до кол-во строк
- Делаете "сдвиг" чтения из файла на это число
- Результат в echo, закрыть файл.

  HTML

- Подключите jQuery
- Ссылку(кнопку), DIV куда выводить цитату
- Вешаете обработчик на кнопку click
- Отправляете AJAX запрос к вашему PHP
- На функцию success меняете text(html) в DIV на результат.
```

Ниже товарищ написал вам PHP, я попробую набросать "front-end":

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result">тут будет цитата</div>
<a id="getdata" href="#">Посмотреть</a>
<script>
$('#getdata').click(function(){
$.ajax({
  url: '/echoscript.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: $('#result').text(),
  success: function(response) { $('#result').text(response) },
  dataType: 'html'
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$data = file('your_file.txt');

$count = count($data); //Количество всех строк

$random_index = mt_rand(0, $count-1); //Генерируем случайный индекс

$value = $data[$random_index]; //Ваша строка
```

P.S. Что из вышеперечисленого вы не смогли "нагуглить"?